# Returning all values in another table that matches one linked value in another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry the title is a bit convoluted!

I've had a little search everywhere but I'm not sure I'm wording it right to get any results or if what I want to do is even possible...

Basically I want to return all values in a table that match a value in another.
I have the tables:

```
Table "Cars"               Table "Models"

Car_ID    Car              Car_ID    Model_ID    Model
-------------------        ----------------------------
1         Ford             1          14         Mustang
2         Fiat             1          21         Focus
3         Toyota           1          87         Escort
                           2          78         500
                           2          45         Punto
                           3          66         Aygo
```

And if I search for just one model name (eg. Escort) I want these results:

```
Car    Model_ID    Model
------------------------
Ford   14          Mustang
Ford   21          Focus
Ford   87          Escort
```

So searching for a car model will return all the models that are the same make.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT c.Car, m.Model_ID, m.Model
FROM Models m
INNER JOIN Cars c ON c.Car_ID = M.Car_ID
WHERE m.Car_ID = (SELECT Car_ID FROM Models WHERE Model = 'Escort');
```

Comment: Yes, it is! I was trying something similar and getting nowhere... I've got it working great now, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query.  If there are multiple models with the same name, this query will return all of the models from all of the corresponding makes of the provided model name.

```
SELECT c.Car, m.Model_ID, m.Model

FROM Models AS m_search

INNER JOIN Cars AS c
ON m_search.Car_ID = c.Car_ID

INNER JOIN Models AS m
ON c.Car_ID = m.Car_ID

WHERE m_search.Model = ?
```

Example on PostgreSQL (since MySQL doesn't support `WITH`):

```
chris=$ WITH Cars (Car_ID, Car) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'Ford'),
    (2, 'Fiat'),
    (3, 'Toyota')
), Models (Car_ID, Model_ID, Model) AS (VALUES
    (1, 14, 'Mustang'),
    (1, 21, 'Focus'),
    (1, 87, 'Escort'),
    (2, 78, '500'),
    (2, 45, 'Punto'),
    (3, 66, 'Agyo')
)

SELECT c.Car, m.Model_ID, m.Model

FROM Models AS m_search

INNER JOIN Cars AS c
ON m_search.Car_ID = c.Car_ID

INNER JOIN Models AS m
ON c.Car_ID = m.Car_ID

WHERE m_search.Model = 'Escort';

 car  | model_id |  model
------+----------+---------
 Ford |       14 | Mustang
 Ford |       21 | Focus
 Ford |       87 | Escort
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This would work fine as long as `Models.Model` is unique, otherwise, you'd get a lot of duplicate rows

Comment: @Andomar: If the models have differing `Model_ID` values, then the rows would by definition not be duplicate.  And if they had the same `Model_ID` then the database schema would be incorrect, since that should be the primary key of `Models`.  ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this solution. I've ended up using Doug Kress' as it's easier for me to understand, but thanks for the answer again and for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 select c.Car, m.Model_ID, m.Model from Cars c, Models m where c.Car_ID=m.Car_ID 
and Car_ID in (select Car_ID from Models where  Model='Escort')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to retrieve the `Car_ID` for a model:

```
select  *
from    Models m
join    Cars c
on      c.Car_ID = m.Car_ID
where   m.Car_ID = 
        (
        select  Car_ID
        from    Models
        where   Model = 'Mustang'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big the tables you're looking at are it can be more efficient to get your information in a sub-query rather than using "in" or joins.

```
select ( select car from cars where car_id = m.car_id ), model_id, model
  from models m
 where car_id = ( select car_id from from models where model = 'Escort' )
```